# Opening multiple TXT files in Notepad++ using VB.net

Tags: notepad++, vb.net-2010

I've written a VB.net program that opens a number of different .txt files in Notepad++, however, having just ran it, it opens a new instance of the program for each .txt file.

This is the line I use ...

`Dim p = Process.Start("Notepad++.exe", myFile1)`

... how can I tell my next file to open in a new Tab, rather than a new instance ...

`Dim p = Process.Start("Notepad++.exe", NewTab, myFile2)` ?

Also, is there a command I can use in VB.net to Close each Tab & then finally Close the instance that I initiated (as there may be another NotePad++ already running) when I am done processing ?

Comment: Are you opening multiple files at the same time, or are you opening one, then at some point in the future opening another?

Comment: Each individual .txt file is opened by a separate VB statement as per my first example above, the only difference in each command is the name of the file. The ",NewTab" expression on the second example is just that, an example to try to show what I am looking for ... if even possible.

Comment: You are definitely going to have to approach this in a different manner. The `Process.Start()` function is going to start a new process, which will result in a new instance of Notepad++. If there is any way to accomplish this, you will have to look through Notepad++ documentation or source code to see if there is an API for adding a new tab to an existing instance of Notepad++.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, that makes sense. The main reason I am using the 'Process.Start()' function is because I was originally opening the standard NotePad program and was resizing the Window afterwards. However, using NotePad++ I don't need to do that, so am not restricted to that method, except probably on the first open, so that everything in this instance of NotePad++ is contained in the one instance, then I could safely close the whole Window at end of processing & not worry about each individual Tab ... would that make it easier / possible ?

Comment: Once the process has been opened, you have to communicate to the process somehow that it needs to open a new tab with the specified file. It is likely the only way this is possible is by communicating with the existing Notepad++ somehow. That would require an API on the Notepad++ side, which I doubt exists. You could write that API and submit it to Notepad++ since it is an open source project.

Comment: Now here's something weird, I changed the options to NOT keep a record of the previously opened files, so that when NotePad++ opens, it opens clean.

I ran a test and it opened one instance of the program with 4 Tabs ... I was delighted.

I then changed a couple of other things, ran another test, and it opened in 4 different instances of NP++ !!!

I'll investigate further after the weekend, but that one threw me a bit !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be purely a timing matter & by delaying each call to NotePad++ by 1/2 a second it is now working OK ... faster PCs than mine may not have this problem !!!